# Orderings and TreeMap

Tags: scala

I'm building a `MultiSet[A]` and using a `TreeMap[A, Int]` to keep track of the elements.

```
class MultiSet[A <: Ordered[A] ](val tm: TreeMap[A, Int]) { ... }
```

Now I want to create a `MultiSet[Int]` using this framework.  In particular, I want a method that will take a `Vector[Int]` and produce a `TreeMap[Int, Int]` that I can use to make a `MultiSet[Int]`.

I wrote the following `vectorToTreeMap`, which compiles without complaint.

```
def vectorToTreeMap[A <: Ordered[A]](elements: Vector[A]): TreeMap[A, Int] =
  elements.foldLeft(new TreeMap[A, Int]())((tm, e) => tm.updated(e, tm.getOrElse(e, 0) + 1))
```

But when I try

```
val tm: TreeMap[Int, Int] = vectorToTreeMap(Vector(1, 2, 3))
```

I get compiler complaints saying that `Int` doesn't conform to `A <: Ordered[A]`. What does it take to create a `TreeMap[Int, Int]` in this context? (I want the more general case because the `MultiSet[A]` is not always `MultiSet[Int]`.)

I also tried `A <: scala.math.Ordered[A]` and `A <: Ordering[A]` but with no better results. (I'll admit that I don't understand the differences among the three possibilities and whether it matters in this situation.)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that *Int* is an alias for the java *int*, which does not implement Ordered[Int]. How could it, since java does not even know that the Ordered[T] trait exists.

There are two ways to solve your problem:

**View bounds**:

The first approach is to change the constraint *<:* to a view bound *<%*.

```
def vectorToTreeMap[A <% Ordered[A]](elements: Vector[A]): TreeMap[A, Int] =
  elements.foldLeft(new TreeMap[A, Int]())((tm, e) => tm.updated(e, tm.getOrElse(e, 0) + 1))
```

*A <: Ordered[A]* means that the method vectorToTreeMap is only defined for types that directly implement Ordered[A], which excludes Int.

*A <% Ordered[A]* means that the method vectorToTreeMap is defined for all types that "can be viewed as" implementing Ordered[A], which includes Int because there is an implicit conversion defined from Int to Ordered[Int]:

```
scala> implicitly[Int => Ordered[Int]]
res7: Int => Ordered[Int] = <function1>
```

**Type classes**

The second approach is to not require any (direct or indirect) inheritance relationship for the type A, but just require that *there exists* a way to order instances of type A.

Basically you always require an ordering to be able to create a TreeMap from a vector, but to avoid having to pass it every single time you call the method you make the ordering an implicit parameter.

```
def vectorToTreeMap[A](elements: Vector[A])(implicit ordering:Ordering[A]): TreeMap[A, Int] =
  elements.foldLeft(new TreeMap[A, Int]())((tm, e) => tm.updated(e, tm.getOrElse(e, 0) + 1))
```

It turns out that there are instances of Ordering[A] for all java primitive types as well as for String, as you can see with the implicitly method in the scala REPL:

```
scala> implicitly[Ordering[Int]]
res8: Ordering[Int] = scala.math.Ordering$Int$@5b748182
```

Scala is even able to *derive* orderings for composite types. For example if you have a Tuple where there exists an ordering for each element type, scala will automatically provide an ordering for the tuple type as well:

```
scala> implicitly[Ordering[(Int, Int)]]
res9: Ordering[(Int, Int)] = scala.math.Ordering$$anon$11@66d51003
```

The second approach of using so-called type classes is much more flexible. For example, if you want a tree of plain old ints, but with reverse order, all you have to do is to provide a reverse int ordering either directly or as an implicit val.

This approach is also very common in idiomatic scala. So there is even special syntax for it:

```
def vectorToTreeMap[A : Ordering](elements: Vector[A]): TreeMap[A, Int] = ???
```

is equivalent to

```
def vectorToTreeMap[A](elements: Vector[A])(implicit ordering:Ordering[A]): TreeMap[A, Int] = ???
```

It basically means that you want the method vectorToTreeMap defined only for types for which an ordering exists, but you do not care about giving the ordering a name. Even with the short syntax you can use vectorToTreeMap with an implicitly resolved Ordering[A], or pass an Ordering[A] explicitly.

The second approach has two big advantages:

- it allows you to define functionality for types you do not "own".
- it allows you to decouple the behavior regarding some aspect like e.g. ordering from the type itself, whereas with the inheritance approach you couple the behavior to the type. For example you can have a normal Ordering and a caseInsensitiveOrdering for a Sting. But if you let String extend from Ordered, you must decide on one ordering behavior.

That is why the second approach is used in the scala collections itself to provide an ordering for [TreeMap](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/TreeMap.scala#L1).

---

Edit: here is an example to provide an ordering for a type that does not have one:

```
scala> case class Person(name:String, surname:String)
defined class Person

scala> implicitly[Ordering[Person]]
<console>:10: error: No implicit Ordering defined for Person.
              implicitly[Ordering[Person]]
                        ^
```

Case classes do not have orderings automatically defined. But we can easily define one:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class Person(name:String, surname:String)

object Person {

  // just convert to a tuple, which is ordered by the individual elements
  val nameSurnameOrdering : Ordering[Person] = Ordering.by(p => (p.name, p.surname))

  // make the nameSurnameOrdering the default that is in scope unless something else is specified
  implicit def defaultOrdering = nameSurnameOrdering
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Person
defined module Person

scala> implicitly[Ordering[Person]]
res1: Ordering[Person] = scala.math.Ordering$$anon$9@50148190
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer. It's answers like this that make Stackoverflow the valuable resource it is.  Are there any good tutorials on Type orderings and how to use and specify them?

Comment: I am not aware of any tutorial specifically for Ordering. But as long as you don't do anything extraordinary things will just work. 

If you want to take a look under the covers, a good start is to look at the companion object of the Ordering trait. That is where much of the functionality that makes things "just work" is defined: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala

Comment: What I'd like in a tutorial on Orderings is (at least) something that would tell me how and when to use the constructs you discuss. I would have no idea how to use them or even that they existed. The only reason I knew about `A <: Ordered[A]` is that I saw it in the answer to another question and hoped that it would help.

Comment: One further question. I want to define an `emptyTreeMap`. The following works. 

    `def emptyTreeMap[A: Ordering]: TreeMap[A, Int] = new TreeMap[A, Int]()`

Can I do the same thing as a val? When I write

    `val emptyTreeMap = new TreeMap[Ordering, Int]()`

I get a compiler diagnostic that says that Ordering takes type parameters. If I try

    `val emptyTreeMap = new TreeMap[Ordering[Int], Int]()`

I get diagnostics that I don't understand. (Sorry about the formatting. Is there a way to put code in comments so that it is legible?)

Comment: I actually agree that a tutorial about Ordering as one of the simple and least intimidating type classes would be a great idea. But I am not aware of any. Regarding an empty TreeMap: this can not possibly be a val because an empty TreeMap[Int] that has a normal ordering is a different object than an empty TreeMap[Int] with e.g. a reverse ordering. An implicit parameter might be invisible, but it is still a parameter. There is no way I am aware of to format code in comments at SO.

Comment: By the way: if you have your MultiMap in a state where it works, you might want to put it on the code review sister site of stackoverflow to get some comments on how to turn it into more idiomatic scala. SO is more for specific questions than for general coding/style advice.